# Is it possible to know which go packages are installed in a binary

Tags: go

I have my go workspace where I develop and then I build a binary and copy it onto a kuberenetes pod and run it. Is it possible to know what go packages are used/installed in the binary?

Comment: if it's your own binary you can just look in the go.mod file

Comment: Or use `go list`.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `go version [-m] [file ...]`

Go version reports the Go version used to build each of the named
executable files.

Output example:

```
$ go version -m dlv
dlv: go1.14.2
        path    github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
        mod     github.com/go-delve/delve       v1.4.0  h1:O+1dw1XBZXqhC6fIPQwGxLlbd2wDRau7NxNhVpw02ag=
        dep     github.com/cosiner/argv v0.0.0-20170225145430-13bacc38a0a5      h1:rIXlvz2IWiupMFlC45cZCXZFvKX/ExBcSLrDy2G0Lp8=
        dep     github.com/mattn/go-isatty      v0.0.3  h1:ns/ykhmWi7G9O+8a448SecJU3nSMBXJfqQkl0upE1jI=
        dep     github.com/peterh/liner v0.0.0-20170317030525-88609521dc4b      h1:8uaXtUkxiy+T/zdLWuxa/PG4so0TPZDZfafFNNSaptE=
        dep     github.com/sirupsen/logrus      v0.0.0-20180523074243-ea8897e79973      h1:3AJZYTzw3gm3TNTt30x0CCKD7GOn2sdd50Hn35fQkGY=
        dep     github.com/spf13/cobra  v0.0.0-20170417170307-b6cb39589372      h1:eRfW1vRS4th8IX2iQeyqQ8cOUNOySvAYJ0IUvTXGoYA=
        dep     github.com/spf13/pflag  v0.0.0-20170417173400-9e4c21054fa1      h1:7bozMfSdo41n2NOc0GsVTTVUiA+Ncaj6pXNpm4UHKys=
        dep     go.starlark.net v0.0.0-20190702223751-32f345186213      h1:lkYv5AKwvvduv5XWP6szk/bvvgO6aDeUujhZQXIFTes=
        dep     golang.org/x/arch       v0.0.0-20190927153633-4e8777c89be4      h1:QlVATYS7JBoZMVaf+cNjb90WD/beKVHnIxFKT4QaHVI=
        dep     golang.org/x/crypto     v0.0.0-20190308221718-c2843e01d9a2      h1:VklqNMn3ovrHsnt90PveolxSbWFaJdECFbxSq0Mqo2M=
        dep     golang.org/x/sys        v0.0.0-20190626221950-04f50cda93cb      h1:fgwFCsaw9buMuxNd6+DQfAuSFqbNiQZpcgJQAgJsK6k=
        dep     gopkg.in/yaml.v2        v2.2.1  h1:mUhvW9EsL+naU5Q3cakzfE91YhliOondGd6ZrsDBHQE=
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes! The `ReadBuildInfo` function in the [runtime/debug](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/) package can give you this information.

According to the docs this function

> returns the build information embedded in the running binary. The information is available only in binaries built with module support.

So, for example, if your project has these files:

*go.mod*

```
module buildinfo

go 1.12

require github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.3
```

*main.go*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime/debug"

    _ "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    buildInfo, ok := debug.ReadBuildInfo()
    if !ok {
        panic("Can't read BuildInfo")
    }
    fmt.Println("Dependencies:")
    for _, dep := range buildInfo.Deps {
        fmt.Printf("  %s %s\n", dep.Path, dep.Version)
    }
}
```

When run it will output:

```
Dependencies:
  github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.3
```

Comment: This is a good starting point, but worth noting that it prints out module dependencies, not packages as the OP asked. So, for example, it will not say that package `runtime/debug` and `fmt` are part of the binary.

Answer (score 1):

given the github-ecosystem, it is most trivial to inspect a binary for included resources;

just inspect the binary for modules;

```
$ strings  ~/bin/txeh | grep github  
/usr/bin/env go run ~/src/github.com/txn2/txeh/util/txeh.go "$@"


$ strings  ~/bin/tt | grep github 
github.com/araddon/dateparse.init.ializers
github.com/araddon/dateparse.init
/home/jaroslav/src/github.com/tox2ik/ttrack/src/tt/main.go
/home/jaroslav/src/github.com/araddon/dateparse/parseany.go
github.com/araddon/dateparse.ErrAmbiguousMMDD
github.com/araddon/dateparse.initdone.
github.com/araddon/dateparse.init.ializers
github.com/araddon/dateparse.init
```

or if you do not know the origin:

```
strings  ~/bin/tt | grep -e '\.go\>' -C2 | sort -ur

/usr/lib/go/src/os/exec_posix.go
/usr/lib/go/src/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s
/usr/lib/go/src/internal/bytealg/count_native.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go
/usr/lib/go/src/os/wait_waitid.go
/usr/lib/go/src/internal/cpu/cpu.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mgclarge.go
/usr/lib/go/src/internal/bytealg/index_amd64.go
/usr/lib/go/src/strings/builder.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/utf8.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/signal_linux_amd64.go
/usr/lib/go/src/os/stat_linux.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mbarrier.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mcache.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go
.elfdata
/usr/lib/go/src/syscall/exec_unix.go
/usr/lib/go/src/runtime/cpuflags_amd64.go
(...)
```